# How do I get back into Windows?

Tags: windows

Windows 7 started giving me a lot of problems lately and I've been wanting to try Ubuntu for awhile, so I got Linux Live USB Creator and the Ubuntu ISO. I didn't have any USBs or blank CDs, so I made it boot from my extra D drive. Now when I turn on my computer, it automatically boots into Ubuntu for some reason and I have no option to get back into Windows. I can press shift on the grub and get into the thing that say boot: but I don't know what to type to make Windows boot.

I'd be fine with not getting back into Windows if Ubuntu would install, but it gives me an error every time I try to install it, so I assume doing it from the CD drive just isn't going to work or something and I need to get back into Windows and undo what I did to my D drive and wait until I get a USB to do it with. But the first problem I have to deal with is how am I supposed to get back into Windows? Right now I can't get into any OS except for Ubuntu's Live Version.

Thanks for any help you can give me.

EDIT: I don't think my computer even recognizes Windows 7 is on it any longer. When Ubuntu tries to install, I don't get the "Install Alongside Windows 7" or "Replace Windows 7 with Ubuntu" (not the exact wording, I know) options, Windows 7 doesn't show up anywhere at all. It's just gone. And I don't see a second hard drive in my laptop, so I think maybe I changed the hard drive itself to an Ubuntu ISO installer. I'm really not sounding like the brightest person right now, I know. When I click on "OS" in Ubuntu Live Version, though, it still has all the Windows files and all the folders from my old C drive from Windows 7. I really don't know what's going on. At this point it looks like the only plausible option is to just take this hard drive out and replace with with a hard drive from my other laptop.

Answer (score 1):

This is weird . Are you sure you didn't install completely Ubuntu in the drive ? 
The only thing I can imaging is the BIOS. Hold down the key during PC boot, to go into BIOS configuration page (in my laptop is <kbd>F2</kbd> , maybe is <kbd>Del</kbd> or <kbd>F10</kbd>) and search for "Device boot priority" or "Boot sequence". See if your **internal HDD** (or the other HDD ,not the extra D drive) is placed first in boot. If not then change it, save and reboot.

If none of above works, then something else is going on and I suggest to boot into BIOS , place first BOOT the DVD and boot from the Windows DVD to repair the installation.

Comment: I'm on the Bios screen but I don't see any Device boot priority. It's got 5 tabs, Main, Advanced, Boot, Security, and Exit. On the Boot tab it says Boot Option Priorities and then Boot Option #1 and Boot Option #2. My two options are WDC WD7500BPVT... and MATSHITADVD-RA... I have no idea what either one of these are, lol

Comment: The WDC is the Western Digital Drive. The other is the DVD. Place first the WDC. If its already first , then something else is going on.

Comment: The WDC was already first. My PC showed two drives on Windows 7, drive C and D and they were separate, but after opening up my laptop now I only see one hard drive. So I think maybe I turned that whole hard drive into something that loads the ISO installer as soon as I turn it on.

Comment: Yes , C: and D: are partitions of the same HDD. I think is time to boot from the Windows DVD and repair your installation.You have to configure the BIOS to boot first from the DVD (MATSHITA)

Comment: Yeah, seems like it. I might just ditch that HDD and put in one from my other laptop anyway. If I install Ubuntu on that one I shouldn't have any of the driver issues I'd have if I left Windows on it, should I?

Comment: You can install Ubuntu alongside Windows. It is almost an automatic procedure. But first you have to repair your Windows installation and make sure that Windows are in place. I edited my answer above.

Comment: When I set MATSHITA to boot first, for some reason it still just boots Ubuntu, so I'm thinking this HDD is just done. If I uninstall Windows on my other laptop HDD and install Ubuntu on it and put it in the laptop I'm having problems with, will it work or will I have driver issues like I would if I left windows on it?

Comment: No drivers issues with Ubuntu. Ubuntu are not Windows. Ubuntu has all (well..most of them) drivers integrated. So it should work almost in every machine.I urge you to do it. :-)

Comment: Alright, that's probably what I'll end up doing. Thanks for all your help and patience!

Comment: I am waiting for the results. Do not forget to configure BIOS when you attach the new HDD in Laptop.